# Stylus Multidimensional Array

Tags: sass, stylus

I have a multidimensional array in SCSS like this

```
    $color: (
       black : (
           1: '#000000',
           2: '#111111',
           3: '#222222'
        ) 
    );
```

This is the indentation type that is supported in stylus.

```
    $color = (black: (1: "#000000", 2: "#111111", 3: "#222222"));
```

How to write the same indent structure in STYLUS like in SCSS ?

Any ideas ? Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stylus Hashes](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/hashes.html) don't support number as key, you have to use string.

```
$color = {
  black: {
    '1': "#000000",
    '2': "#111111",
    '3': "#222222",
  }
}

.foo
  color:$color.black['2'];
```

[try it online](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=%24color%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20black%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'1'%3A%20%22%23000000%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'2'%3A%20%22%23111111%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'3'%3A%20%22%23222222%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A.foo%0A%20%20color%3A%24color.black%5B'2'%5D%3B)